# What's the point of writing : $foo = & new someClass();?

Tags: php, new-operator, instantiation

I am getting a deprecated warning because of a library I am using. The statement is the following :

```
$this->_ole =& new OLERead();
```

The thing is I don't see why one would want to use `& new` in an instantiation.

If I am not mistaken, the `&` operator tells PHP to copy the reference to the instance, and not the instance itself. But in that case, isn't it pointless to ask for a copy of a reference that isn't stored ?

But since I don't exactly know how `new` exactly works, maybe this was supposed to save some obscure garbage collection, or something like that.

What do you think about that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> As of PHP 5, the [new](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) operator returns a reference automatically, so assigning the result of [new](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) by reference results in an **`E_DEPRECATED`** message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an **`E_STRICT`** message in earlier versions.

The library you use was probably developed for PHP 4.

Helpful information about *why* this was used can also be found in the [migration guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php):

> In PHP 5 there is a new Object Model. PHP's handling of objects has been completely rewritten, allowing for better performance and more features. In previous versions of PHP, objects were handled like primitive types (for instance integers and strings). The drawback of this method was that semantically the whole object was copied when a variable was assigned, or passed as a parameter to a method. In the new approach, objects are referenced by handle, and not by value (one can think of a handle as an object's identifier).

Comment: My bad, I should have found it. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

That's an idiom for PHP4 compatibility. Objects were passed as copies per default there, and this is a workaround to always have references to an instance.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP4, `new` returned a value and not a reference.

This is not the case in PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `$this->_old =& new OLERead();` a changement of _ole in any object will updates all references to the new object.

This is not the case without & .

EDIT: And yes, in previous versions of PHP, object were passed by copy. At the end, this is quite hard to have a consistent behaviour accross versions.

Comment: Objects are *always* passed by reference in PHP >= 5.

Comment: Yes, but just try it, you'll notice that the behaviour mentionned in my post exists. I actually faced that issue hacking code igniter's core.